# Faceted filtering using Postgres & Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, faceted-search

What is the best way to implement a faceted search/filter UI using Postgres as the backend and Ruby on Rails as the front end? Example of this is below:

[image: faceted filtering example]

Comment: Take a look at the `pg_search` gem. https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ThinkingSphinx or Apache Solr - both have built-in faceting.  You can roll your own (as shown in another fine answer) but my experience says that you're better off adding a real search engine and taking advantage of the faceting feature there, as well as the other search features.  I use Solr for all new development, but ThinkingSphinx is generally a little easier to set up and it has new features (main one being continuous indexing) that make it a good contender.

Comment: I've been using ElasticSearch on another project and it has been great for this, but I don't have the same resources for this so it needs to be doable directly in the DB or with Rails.

Comment: I agree with Michael, this solution is much cleaner. However, if you run a little app with a few records, it is a bit overkill imo

Answer (score 0):

I think Rails is powerful enough to implement simple form filters like shown above.

You just need to have a good data model and then it will be easy as pie.

Example:

[image: E/R example]

To simplify the form creation though you can use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), but it is definitely optional.

Comment: This is a great example. How do I get the facet result counts from Postgres, like Color: {Blue: 50, Red: 25, Black: 182}, Size: {Compact: 75, Midsize: 122}, etc.?

Comment: You can do a select count from colour, join cars and then group by colour. Same thing for sizes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    (
        select json_object_agg(COALESCE(brand_id, 'null'), cnt)
        from (
            select brand_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
            from unnest(array_agg(brand_id)) as tmp(brand_id)
            group by brand_id
        ) ttt
    ),
    min(price) as price_min,
    max(price) as price_max
from product
WHERE is_visible = true
```

Comment: Note that while the SQL looks good, I don't think this answers the original question which was: "how to accomplish this via UI given a Postgres back-end and RoR front-end".   I think a more complete answer would include: "call a paginated api endpoint that runs a query similar to the one in the answer".